# Python screen is black for a small amount of time then closes

Tags: python, pygame

The code in this gist (https://gist.github.com/tobias76/8dc2e1af90f1916a2106) is completely broken and nothing happens excl. a black screen and closure after seconds, I would be more specific with the code but there is absolutely no error message. As far as the program is concerned, it worked. As requested, here is my code (For some reason stack overflow doesn't like all of the code being formatted);

==============================================

```
    import pygame
    import sys
    import random

    from pygame.locals import *

    pygame.init()

    FPS = 60
    FPSClock = pygame.time.Clock()

    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
    pygame.display.set_caption("Graphical Slot Machine")

    reelgroupone = pygame.sprite.Group()
    reelgrouptwo = pygame.sprite.Group()
    reelgroupthree = pygame.sprite.Group()

    reelone = (reelgroupone, 1)
    reeltwo = (reelgrouptwo, 2)
    reelthree = (reelgroupthree, 3)

    image = "assets/apple.png"
    image2 = "assets/bar.png"
    image3 = "assets/cherry.png"
    image4 = "assets/orange.png"
    background = "background.jpg"

    class Reels(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
        def __init__(self, reelgroup, reelnumbers):
            self.reelgroup = reelgroup
            self.reelnumber = reelnumbers
            self.reellist = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
            self.reelmove = 1
            self.reelnudge = 0
            self.stoptime = 60

        def start(self):
             self.reelmove = 1
        self.stoptime = 60

    def stop(self):
        self.reelmove = 0

    def update(self):
        if self.stoptime > 0:
            self.stoptime -= 1
            self.reelgroup.update()
        else:
            self.stop()
        if self.reelnudge == 1:
            self.reelmove = 0

    def draw(self):
        self.reelgroup.draw(screen)

class Fruit(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, reelgroup, reel, FruitID):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.reelgroup = reelgroup
        self.FruitID = FruitID
        self.machineReel = reel

        # Depending on Reel ID use a specific image, place the file path in the string
        if self.FruitID == 1:
            self.reelImage = "assets/apple.png"
        if self.FruitID == 2:
            self.reelImage = "assets/bar.png"
        if self.FruitID == 3:
            self.reelImage = "assets/cherry.png"
        if self.FruitID == 4:
            self.picture = "assets/orange.png"

        self.pic = pygame.image.load(self.reelImage).convert_alpha()
        self.where = ((self.machineReel * 155) - 30, 490)
        self.rectangle = self.pic.get_rect()
        self.rectangle.TopLeft = self.where
        # Make reels faster / slower here.
        self.reelSpeed = 8
        self.reelgroup.add(self)

    def fruitupdate(self):
        self.rectangle.y -= self.reelSpeed
        if self.rectangle.y < 110:
            self.kill()


class main():
    def __init__(self):
        self.money = 10
        self.counter = 5
        self.fruitlist = [[0,0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0,0]]
        self.finished = 0
        self.message = ""

    def splash(self):
        pass

    def machine(self):
        while self.credits > 0:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    pygame.quit()
                    sys.exit()
            self.keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

            # Change this key to whatever you want
            if self.keys[K_p] and reelone.reelmove == reeltwo.reelmove == reelthree.reelmove == 0:
                self.money -= 1
                self.counter = 5
                self.finished = 0
                reelone.start()
                reeltwo.start()
                reelthree.start()
                self.message = ""
            if self.keys[K_ESCAPE]:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()

            # Put your image and font blitting here.

            screen.blit(background,(0,0))

            if self.money >= 10:
                self.counter = 1
                if reelone.reelMove == 1 and reelone.stopTime % 10:
                    fruit = Fruit(reelgroupone, 1, random.randint(1,4))
                    del self.fruitlist[0][0]
                    self.fruitlist[0].append(fruit.ID)
                if reeltwo.reelMove == 1 and reeltwo.stopTime % 10:
                    fruit = Fruit(reelgrouptwo, 2, random.randint(1,4))
                    del self.fruitlist[1][0]
                    self.fruitlist[1].append(fruit.ID)
                if reelthree.reelMove == 1 and reelthree.stopTime % 10:
                    fruit = Fruit(reelgroupthree, 3, random.randint(1,4))
                    del self.fruitlist[2][0]
                    self.fruitlist[2].append(fruit.ID)
                else:
                    self.counter += 1
                if reelone.reelmove == 1:
                    reelone.update()
                if reeltwo.reelmove == 1:
                    reeltwo.update()
                if reelthree.reelmove == 1:
                    reelthree.update()

                # If all the reels are moving, check if the player has won and add the credits to their
                # account if so.
                if reelone.reelmove == reeltwo.reelmove == reelthree.reelmove == 0 and self.finished == 0:
                    if self.fruitlist[0][2] == self.fruitlist[1][2] ==  self.fruitlist[2][2]:
                        self.message = "Winner, want to play again?"
                        if self.fruitlist[0][2] == 1:
                            self.credits += 10
                        if self.fruitlist[0][2] == 1:
                            self.credits += 100
                        if self.fruitlist[0][2] == 3:
                            self.credits += 1000
                        if self.fruitlist[0][2] == 4:
                            self.credits += 10000
                        # Now this sets the state to finished
                        self.finished = 1
                    else:
                        self.message = "Sorry, no win this time!"
                        self.end = 1

            reelgroupone.draw(screen)
            reelgrouptwo.draw(screen)
            reelgroupthree.draw(screen)

    FPSClock.tick(FPS)
    pygame.display.update()

fruit = main()
```

Comment: No error message? What about the type error in the traceback?

Comment: C:\Python34\python.exe "F:/Source Code/Python/richardSlotMachine/Main.py"

Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: That is not what the linked source says. You need to put the relevant source here, not externally.

Comment: Oops, wrong one. https://gist.github.com/tobias76/8dc2e1af90f1916a2106 , would you prefer me to copy and paste it into a comment?

Comment: No, you need to put it in your question. Not a link, the actual code.

Comment: You are the Viral Game Studios and this is of difficulty?

Comment: I've added the code to the question, sorry for the formatting.

Answer (score 1):

You're not actually running the main() as a function in your code, main is a class instead. Change main to a function, and instead, write this at the bottom of the program:

```
If __name__ == "__main__": 
    main()
```

This way, the code actually runs. Also, get rid of `fruit = main()`. It just makes it more confusing and you're going to be running it anyways with this, hence why it says that the process finished. You may also want to move things previously in the main class in the main function. For example, take functions inside of the class such as the machine() function and put it as a separate function outside of your code, and call it in the main function with machine().